# How to set image from Firebase Storage in Unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I'm struggling with Unity and Firebase Storage now. I want to fetch images stored in Firebase Storage, set it as texture, and assign the texture as material. However, red question mark appears in the scene like the picture. I tried to find the solution but I couldn't find out. This is my code.

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject plane;
    public Material testMaterial;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Get a reference to the storage service, using the default Firebase App
        Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage storage = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;

        Firebase.Storage.StorageReference storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("removed for question");

        byte[] fileContents = null;

        storage_ref.Child("redHeart.png").GetBytesAsync(1024 * 1024)
         .ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
         {
             if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
             {
                 Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
             }
             else
             {
                fileContents = task.Result;
             }
         });

        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1024, 1024);
        texture.LoadImage(fileContents);
        testMaterial.SetTexture("_MainTex", texture);
        plane.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = testMaterial;
        Debug.Log("finished");
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWAls.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, I would like to answer it.
I think there might be a problem with the async function which runs after loading the Image.
Try this one. After storing it, then you can display it. 
Something like this,

```
Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage storage = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;

Firebase.Storage.StorageReference storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("removed for question");

storage_ref.Child("redHeart.png").GetBytesAsync(1024 * 1024)
     .ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
         {
             if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
             {
                 Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
             }
             else
             {
               byte[] fileContents = task.Result;
               Debug.Log("Load Image after getting result!");

               Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1024, 1024);
               texture.LoadImage(fileContents);
               testMaterial.SetTexture("_MainTex", texture);
               plane.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = testMaterial;
               Debug.Log("finished");
             }
         });
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I changed my code to what you advised, except for Texture2D(because an another error happened). And I also changed from ".ContinueWith" to ".ContinueWithOnMainThread". Finally it works. Thank you very much and sorry for my clumsy English.